# VB .net queue strange behaviour with threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, queue, thread-safety

I'm writing an vb .net form application for receiving data from commport, parsing on commport_thread and send messages to UI thread through queue.

App structure looks like this:

```
Private _SerialCommunicationThread As Thread
Public _DataQueue As Queue = Queue.Synchronized(New Queue())
Dim QueueLock As New Object
...
Me._SerialCommunicationThread = New Thread(AddressOf THREAD_SerialCommunication)
Me._SerialCommunicationThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
Me._SerialCommunicationThread.Start()

Private Sub THREAD_SerialCommunication()
  'comm port new instace, settings, start, etc

  do
  ' copy all commport's existing bytes to rec_buffer
  ' parse data in rec_buffer ( my own protocol, every message has 14bytes, last is CRC sum), copy valid message (14 baytes) to buffer_work
  if (CRC is OK) then
    SyncLock QueueLock 'lock queue for adding message
       Me._DataQueue.Enqueue(buffer_work) ' add message
       'Console.WriteLine(received_messages_counter & " ID: " & buffer_work(4) & " val:" & buffer_work(5)) 
       'buffer_work(4) is message ID byte            
       'buffer_work(5) is value byte           
    End SyncLock
  end if

  loop

End sub

...
'UI main thread
Private Sub Timer1_Tick ' interval=10ms
  while Form1._DataQueue.Count > 0 Then
    SyncLock QueueLock
      buf_can = Form1._DataQueue.Dequeue()
      'Console.WriteLine(received_messages_counter2 & " ID: " & buffer_work(4) & " val:" & buffer_work(5)
    End SyncLock
  end while
end sub
```

I'm sending data to COM port from microcontroler:

```
for(i=0,i<50;++i)
{
send_message(ID_100,i); // send message with ID=100 and data=i
send_message(ID_201,i);
send_message(ID_202,i);
};
```

And till parsing procedure and adding to queue console in commport thread writes exactly what is send and copy of message in buffer_work is enqueue:

```
1 ID: 100 val:0
2 ID: 200 val:0
3 ID: 201 val:0
4 ID: 100 val:1
5 ID: 200 val:1
6 ID: 201 val:1
...
148 ID: 100 val:49
149 ID: 200 val:49
150 ID: 201 val:49
```

but here comes the problem, the UI thread gives:

```
...
131 ID: 201 val:43
132 ID: 201 val:43
133 ID: 200 val:44
134 ID: 200 val:44
135 ID: 200 val:45
136 ID: 200 val:45
137 ID: 200 val:45
138 ID: 100 val:46
139 ID: 100 val:46
140 ID: 100 val:47
141 ID: 100 val:47
142 ID: 100 val:47
143 ID: 100 val:48
144 ID: 100 val:48
145 ID: 100 val:48
146 ID: 201 val:48
147 ID: 201 val:48
148 ID: 201 val:49
149 ID: 201 val:49
150 ID: 201 val:49
```

so I get exactly 150 messages but it looks like queue is enqueue in strange way...adding the same message several times, not exactly what is in buffer_work...and at the end of transmision I should have 3x49 values  at 100,201 and 202 ID, but it isn't.
I thought that fifo queue behaves like enqueue A,B,C and I dequeue getting C,B,A. OK, it works but when I enqueue all messages and after that I dequeue.

When I add conditional in main UI thread:

```
If Form1._DataQueue.Count = 150 Then
```

so waiting to enqueue all 150 parsed messages in comm thread, then console prints 150 same messages received in UI thread, those all are the last sent message

```
...
145 ID: 201 val:49
146 ID: 201 val:49
147 ID: 201 val:49
148 ID: 201 val:49
149 ID: 201 val:49
150 ID: 201 val:49
```

So queue looks like to be an 1-element queue, but I need that queue will be message buffer between commport thread and UI thread, so no messaged will be lost... even if UI thread will be activ for a little longer time...

Thank you for any help and tips how to solve this problem...
Regards!

Comment: If you want a queue that can be accessed on multiple threads then use a `ConcurrentQueue(Of T)`. That's exactly what it exists for.

Comment: Problem solved. Reason was buffer_work was declared as global (public). I moved declaration to do ...loop and now is OK, no messages are lost.